# Export list as separate files from a loaded workbook

Tags: r, list, loops

I am using R to in order to split a data set by 100+ ways and then take the split data-sets and export them into a template. Specifically, I am using XLConnect and DPLYR packages to split the dataset and it creates a list. Then, I want to take each item in the list and export it to the 'template' (loaded workbook) and save it as a unique name.

However, I don't know how to saveas using a unique name. In the example I give below, the code saves each item as the same name. I need the title of the workbook to change so that I can have 100X files. Meaning, I want to the title of the workbook to change based on the "LvL1_Mgr" name. Thoughts?

```
Example Below.

library(readxl)
    SurveyDataRaw <- read_excel("~/SurveyDataRaw.xlsx")

#distinct leaders
library(dplyr)
Leaders_in_file <- SurveyDataRaw %>%
  distinct(Lvl1_Mgr)

#store leader names as list
Leaders_in_file <- as.list(Leaders_in_file)

Sam2 <- SurveyDataRaw %>%
      group_by(Lvl1_Mgr, Q_Short) %>%
      summarise(Q_Responses = mean(Q_Response, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
      split(.,.$Lvl1_Mgr)

#THis is where I get the problem. All files are being created successfully, 
but #the save over each other.
for(i in Sam2){
  wb <- loadWorkbook("Test123456.xlsx", create = TRUE)
  wb["TestSheetName"] = i
  saveWorkbook(wb, Create=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Given we don't have your data it's tough. Can you `dput` one of the data frames? Are you trying to save all of the list items to a tab in the new workbook, or create a new workbook for each list item?

Comment: *"Title of the workbook to change"*: is that name of the workbook file, or name of the (single?) worksheet in the workbook?

Comment: I can't find `readxl::saveWorkbook`. Are you using `openxlsx` instead/also?

Comment: I am trying to export each of the items in the list to a specific sheet in the workbook. Then, save the workbook as a unique name. Yes - am using library(XLConnect) to save the workbook. Sorry for not stating that earlier. Test123456.xlsx is the name of the workbook. TestSheetName is the name of the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps one of these will work better for you?

One file, each "model" gets its own worksheet within the workbook:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook("Test123456.xlsx", create = TRUE)
for (s in names(Sam2)) {
  addWorksheet(wb, s)
  writeDataTable(wb, s, Sam2[[s]])
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "Test123456.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

or perhaps a new workbook for each model?

```
for (s in names(Sam2)) {
  wb <- loadWorkbook("Test123456.xlsx", create = TRUE)
  addWorksheet(wb, "SomeName")
  writeDataTable(wb, "SomeName", Sam2[[s]])
  saveWorkbook(wb, sprintf("Test123456-%s.xlsx", s))
}
```

**Edit**:

Potential `XLConnect` version, based on comments:

```
library(XLConnect)
for (s in names(Sam2)) {
  # if it's an already-created template, no need to 'create'
  wb <- loadWorkbook("Test123456.xlsx", create = FALSE)
  writeWorksheet(wb, Sam2[[s]], "SomeName")
  saveWorkbook(wb)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, when I run the two above suggestions it does not work. I am using XLConnect, and when I use openxlsx, the saveworkbook and loadworkbook are masked....

Comment: I understand. I had problems at one point with `XLConnect` so I migrated to `openxlsx`. Is there something you need that is not offered in the latter? Just wondering ...

Comment: No particular reason I am using XLConnect. My main goal is to create a template in Excel (the final deliverable I am sending to my boss), then use R to manipulate the data and paste it in the Excel template. Essentially, I need 100+ excel documents that look the same and I get do everything but save the document as a unique name.... suggestions?

Comment: See the edit ... it should be directly translateable between the two packages: though the function names are slightly different, the *effects* are nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the help. Final code below.

```
 for (s in names(Sam2)) {
      wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create = FALSE)
      writeWorksheet(wb, Sam2[[s]], "test")
      saveWorkbook(wb, sprintf("%s.xlsx", s))
    }
```